# TicTacToe game error checking and classes

Tags: java, swing, class

I am currently making a TicTacToe program for an assignment in college. I have my board laid out with 3x3 JTextFields, each one has an action listener attached. What I need to do is create another class which will check for errors (eg a user will put a number or a letter that is NOT x or o) they should get a dialog box stating the error and the JTextField they tried to enter will return to blank. How would I go about implementing the error checking, through try - catch - finally method?

Another question, I have a GameGUI class, I also want to have a GameLogic class. How do I check from GameLogic if the game has been won? In my GameLogic I will have something like

if j1, j2 and j3 are all x or o then display dialog box "x player wins".

Comment: error checking is a straightforward procedure involving you in the debug session.

Comment: You seem to know what to use, have you tried to implement your ideas?

Comment: I highly advise you to use buttons instead of textfields. Then using a field variable you can auto populate whether it was X turn or O turn. As far as the second class, you will need to have a reference to the first class. What you can do is give it a class variable such as `logic.game = game`. Then you can use logic.game anywhere in logic class.

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms as per request of the professor, we are not allowed to use buttons sadly, it seems much easier for me if I could. 
JordanD yes and no, I am only familiar with some error checking, could you point me in the right direction for using check-catch-finally?

Comment: I think some very simple If Else checking would be sufficient without having to handle any sort of exceptions here. `if (turn.equals(textfield.text().toString()){do stuff}else{tell them its wrong}

On another note. If your prof said no buttons you can take advantage of treating labels as buttons. They are not exactly buttons, but can be treated as one.

Comment: Since this is an assignment, I will state the obvious.. Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the question regarding a general board game. Your object oriented thinking of splitting into different classes is correct. What I do generally is that I have the GameLogic containing my logic and validations for the game as well as determining whether the game is over or not and so on.

The GameGUI class would then have an instance variable of the type GameLogic that's initialized on creating an object of type GameGUI. In my way of thinking, I would have the GameLogic representing the board state with 2D Array of chars. The GameGUI would be just there to relay input from the user to the GameLogic which determines if the game is over. The GameLogic should throw an Exception of the type that you want to clarify and then the GameGUI should try to update the board with the input text from the user in the JText fields, catch the error from the GameLogic (if any) and then repaint the GUI that's displayed to the user based on the input it got. I will give a sample below to clarify my point although I won't provide the actual implementation for the TicTacToe game, you can easily do it on your own.

```
public class GameLogic {
    ....
    char[][]board;
    public GameLogic() {
       //initialize the board representation for game
    }
    public boolean gameOver() {
       //determine if the game is over by checking the board 2D array
       // 3 xs or os in a row, column, or diagonal should determine the game is over or if there are no more moves
    }
    public void move(char character, int x, int y) {
       //update a certain position with a character should throw an Exception if the character is invalid or if the the character is valid but it's not the character that the user owns player1 plays with x for example but puts o.
      //should also have the logic for the turns
    }
    ...
}

public class GameGUI {
    .....
    GameLogic engine;
    public GameGUI() {
        engine = new GameLogic();   
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // here you would get the co-ordinates of the clicked JTextButton
        // then call the method move on the engine instance
        try {
            engine.move(character, x, y);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //display the validation for the error that happened
        }
        //repaint the representation from the engine to be displayed on the GUI Frame that you are using
    }
    ...
}
```

One more thing is that I would have declared the JTextFields as 2D Array of JTextFields and not as individual instance variables to mirror the representation in the GameLogic class. You can also avoid the validations all together if you use JButton class instead of JTextField and that the user gets the character he is playing with on the clicked button if it is his turn and the button is not already used before.